# Wordpress Extremely Slow On Remote Database

Tags: wordpress

I'm learning some PHP + wordpress.
For having an ability of working everywhere without care of current content sync e.g. from desktop computers in several locations and laptops as well, I use unified MySQL database, that I can connect from any device.

The problem is that WORDPRESS is extremely slow always I use remote DB.

I tried several DB points such as AWS, ORACLE, and couple of VPS I run for that, but every trying I did I could not consider to be successful, compare to my local DB connection.

For example an amount of time to reload simple WP page with a bit of text, CSS and optimized images:

AWS ~ 5 sec.
VPS(Location A) ~ 2.9 sec.
VPS(Location B) ~ 3.8 sec.
Local DB ~ 0.05 - 0.14 sec.

Of course it's very annoying having to wait about of ~3 sec for reviewing a page.
Connection with other app of those locations is OK, ping to server is about of ~47-120 ms and speed is good (~50-100 mb/s),  so I can flawlessly stream video, downloads files e.t.c. through those servers without any issues.

What do you think, is that normal ?
Is that WP or DB issues ?
And what would you advice me in that regards ?

Comment: We cannot tell you what causes the issue - you need test it  yourself.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're hosting on Wordpress on one server and MySQL on another? That means network latency on each query, though that may not be the actual issue.

Comment: yes, true. on each computers I'm working currently I'm running Apache which uses same folder with WordPress files (which are itself synced between machines through git)

Comment: If I could sync a local database state on each computer between each other, it would be a deal, but I can't.

Comment: Of course I can try running Apache on the server where DBs running, but, anyway I wonder, where that latency come from. And what if in the real case some would be in need to part DB and server on different points.